# php background job cause exception on memory_limit

Tags: php, background, jobs

if i have a php background job, may need to run 4-5hours or more
will it cause exception on memory_limit

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: time has not necessarily a relevance with memory. If your php script needs to allocate more than the memory that it is allowed to in the configuration, a memory limit exception will occur. If not, there will not be such an exception irregardless how long it runs, however, if called by apache it probably give you a timeout exception, called directly (i.e. php via cron) it does not.

Comment: Actually i have a process to sent our over 25000 email, and sleep 30 sec for every 20 emails sent, i found that using background job, sent out 10000 is no problem, but sent 25000 just stop at 2610's email...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a very primitive memory manager and scripts are not designed to run for very long.   You can update the memory limit like this:

```
<?php ini_set(“memory_limit”,”256M”); ?>
```

But you will probably still have memory problems.  You could try adding a ton of unset()'s to your script and this can help a bit.   But the memory leaks are probably in PHP and its C/C++ extensions which you can't control.   In the past I have had to rewrite background tasks in Java.

Comment: actually my script is very simple, get email data from db and send them out and sleep 30 sec by every 20 email sent

it is really really simple srcipt, so i have no idea to rewrite

Comment: You could setup a cron job to run it every minute, have it execute for 20 email and then exit.   This way the memory will always remain low and this is in line with how PHP wants it's scripts to run.

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini increase the amount for memory_limit.

See http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/14/increase-php-memory-limit/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following PHP commands:

```
// Sets the max time in seconds the script can run
set_time_limit($sec);
// Increases the memory limit (default is 1.5mb)
ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");
```

Comment: Thx, i knew it already, i think if over 256mb, what will happen?

Comment: Then you have a serious memory leak.  If you are passing objects/arrays into repetitive functions, be aware you are copying that data into a new variable.  Think about using some globals instead.